# Scaling a group of shapes in Diagramly

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I group shapes together in Diagramly, I want to rescale those shapes all at once as a group, but I can't see any way to do that. I obviously dragged one of the corner handles of the group frame but it does not work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

It took sometime for me to find out that option. Its very simple.

- Select all the shapes you want to scale.
- Then click on the "Arrange" tab.
- Then click "Group" button.
- This will give you a new box outside your selection. Now resize/move this box to scale your graph.
- Once you are done, you can similarly ungroup it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Currently, in draw.io, setting the font size and other properties of a group does nothing to the elements, but for a number of selected items, it does. So the work flow for a single group is: ungroup (^u); set attribute; group (^g).

Note that this **sets** attributes such as font size; attributes that differ betweeen elements will not be scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked and the most recent answer was given (2018), a new way of resizing multiple objects was added:

Simply select multiple objects and navigate to "Arrange", where you'll find two input fields for their width and height. The object anchor is at its top left, so increasing the width expands to the right and increasing the height expands downward.

[image: Screenshot of "Arrange" view with width and height fields]